# I can't to get Label and Buttons components in created window

Tags: java, user-interface

I tryed to learn about GUI and tryed to create the window with two buttons and jne Label on the screen. But I don't understand why I can't see these elements simultaneously. When I comment out lines for buttons I can see the Label element.
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyWin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame w = new JFrame("My Window");
        w.setSize(1000,800);
        w.setVisible(true);

        JButton b = new JButton("My button");
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.setSize(150, 100);
        b.setLocation(500, 20);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Second button");
        b2.setVisible(true);
        b2.setSize(150,100);
        b2.setLocation(500, 600);

        JLabel l = new JLabel("My label");
        l.setVisible(true);

        w.getContentPane().add(b);
        w.getContentPane().add(b2);
        w.getContentPane().add(l);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default layout for the `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` and when you add your `JLabel` through single parameter `add` method you add it with a `BorderLayour.CENTER` constraint as a default, this causes to fill all the available space. So you might want to use layout manager suitable for your needs, then the components won't overlay themselves.

[Visual Guide to Layour Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JFrame uses BorderLayout as a default layout and just adding the components (`w.getContentPane().add(b)`) sets them in `BorderLayout.CENTER;` where they occupy the whole JFrame to fill the empty space. Thus, is recommended to add components in a JPanel. So, you should create first a JPanel, add the components to the JPanel **and** finally add it to the JFrame.

The `setSize(...);` statement is not applied due to the default layout (FlowLayout) in JPanels and also is discouraged. (Because it won't work properly in different computers with different screen resolutions)

If you want to change the size of the components you should change the default layout and use instead a customLayout, borderLayout, gridLayout...

If you want to understand deeply how layouts work and all the available layouts in Java check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)